# module.GetUUIDString() is nil in linux but working fine in Mac for same .app and crashlog file

Tags: ios, linux, macos, lldb, symbolicate

I am creating a lldb parser to symbolicate crashlog. Parser is working fine in mac machine but not in Linux(VirtualBox).

After debugging python script I found that module.GetUUIDString() is giving nil in linux machine where module `<lldb.SBModule; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'lldb::SBModule *' at 0x10c0181e0> >` is created successfully

After debugging more, I found out that in Linux machine, createTarget command is giving error.

`ErrorType =1` //Not sure what is this?
Error.Success = false
Description: binary doesn't contain the architecture **aarch64**. //where is I am giving arm64.

In Mac this command is working fine with same set of log and binary.
'error', True)
('error', 0)

Comment: What is the code you use to create the target?

Comment: @JimIngham `debugger.CreateTarget ('binaryPath', 'arm64',None, dependents, error)` But the error is coming like 'binary doesn't contain the architecture aarch64'

Comment: If you just use the CreateTarget API that just takes a binary path, does that work?  You should only have to provide the architecture if the binary is a Universal one.  If you can get that to work then you can use SBTarget.GetTriple() to tell you what IT thinks its architecture is...

Comment: @JimIngham, For Mac, there was no need to give arch. But for linux, it was throwing error. Result of `SBTarget.GetTriple()` was `arm64-apple-ios13.2.0` in mac so I used that in linux command. Now the error is coming `doesn't contain any 'remote-ios' platform architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7f, armv7k, armv7s, armv7m, armv7em, armv6m, armv6, armv5, armv4, arm, thumbv7, thumbv7k, thumbv7s, thumbv7f, thumbv7m, thumbv7em, thumbv6m, thumbv6, thumbv5, thumbv4t, thumb"`

Comment: That is starting to sound like you have an lldb that doesn't have support for mach-o compiled in.  I don't actually know much about linux lldb distributions, however...